# не работает QAbstractSocket.setReadBufferSize (python)

Tags: python, сокет, python-2.x, pyqt4, клиент-сервер

Всем здравствуйте. В моем приложении я пытаюсь транслировать изображение с экрана на другой компьютер. Осуществляю я это следующим образом: делаю скрин рабочего стола и через qtcpsocket.write() отправляю на другой комп. Там я это изображение отрисовываю на виджете. Использую QDataStream. В отправляемом сообщении указываю размер изображения, чтобы на принимающей стороне склеить изображение из того же количества байт.Проблема заключается в том, что вскоре после начала работы программы в буфере сокета принимающей стороны оказывается больше байт, чем указано с помощью setReadBufferSize. Почему такое происходит?

Вот код, отправляющий сообщение:

```
screen_pm = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())

ba = QByteArray()
buf = QBuffer(ba)
buf.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
screen_pm.save(buf, 'jpg')

self.request = QByteArray()
stream = QDataStream(self.request, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_4_2)
stream.writeUInt32(ba.size())
stream.writeBytes(ba)
str(s.write(self.request))
self.request.clear()
```

Код, принимающий сообщение:

```
def readFromServer(self):
    if client.socket.bytesAvailable() > 0:
        if client.nextBlockSize == 0:
            client.nextBlockSize = self.stream.readUInt32()
            client.socket.setReadBufferSize(client.nextBlockSize)
        if client.socket.bytesAvailable() == client.socket.readBufferSize() + 4:
            if self.screen.isHidden():
                self.screen.show()
            self.ba = self.stream.readBytes()
            self.pm.loadFromData(self.ba, 'ppm')
            self.screen.graphics_scene.clear()
            self.screen.graphics_scene.addPixmap(self.pm)
            form.client.nextBlockSize = 0
```